# Rails 5 fields_for only sends last params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

I have been hitting my head against a brick wall so it is time to seek smarter people.

I am trying to create multiple records of one model using form_tag and fields_for. I have been following all the help/issues/guides I can find but it doesn't seem to work for me. I am wondering if it something that changed going to Rails 5 but more likely it is me.

Basically I want a new/create version of the task system listed at the bottom of the [api page](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for), similar to [this guys puppy creator](http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/).

The "new" page loads fine with as many records as I like, so that part is ok but it doesn't seem to be creating a collection to send through, it is just overriding and thus sending through the last set of params so only creating one record.

What I have.

```
# routes
resources :container_returns
```

controller

```
# container returns controller
def new
  @containers = Container.where(id: params[:container_ids])
  @container_returns = []
  @containers.each do |container|
    @container_returns << ContainerReturn.new(
      {
        container_id: container.id,
        quantity: container.amount,
        uom: container.uom,
        material_restriction_id: container.material_restriction_id
      }
    )
  end  
end
```

view

```
# new.html.erb
<%= form_tag container_returns_path, method: :post do %>

  <% @container_returns.each do |container_return| %>
    <%= fields_for 'returns[]', container_return, hidden_field_id: true do |cr| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= cr.label :container_id %>
        <%= cr.number_field :container_id %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= cr.label :material_restriction_id %>
        <%= cr.number_field :material_restriction_id %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= cr.label :quantity %>
        <%= cr.text_field :quantity %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= cr.label :uom %>
        <%= cr.text_field :uom %>
      </div>

    <% end %>        
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag "lots of returns" %>

<% end %>
```

which submits

```
# params submitted
Started POST "/container_returns" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-19 11:00:48 +0200
Processing by ContainerReturnsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>[removed],
  "returns"=>{"container_id"=>"405", "material_restriction_id"=>"", "quantity"=>"100.0", "uom"=>"kg"}, "commit"=>"lots of returns"
}
```

hopefully it is just something stupid that I missed.

UPDATE:
if I add an index to the form it now believes me that my objects are different and sends through all the params I need.

```
<% @container_returns.each_with_index do |container_return, index| %>
  <%= fields_for 'returns[]', container_return, index: index do |cr| %>
  [...]
```

Comment: Check the size of `@containers`. If there is only one container with `params[:container_ids]`, then only one `container_return` is initialized and only tis `params` are passed.

Comment: Hi, in my test I have 4 containers, each of which render on the new form. So all are there, so that is not the problem.

Comment: does it change anything if you remove the `hidden_field_id: true` from the fields_for?

Comment: Ok, try changing `'returns[]'` to `'container_returns[]'` inside the `fields_for`

Comment: What if you change `fields_for` to `<%= fields_for container_return do |cr| %>`?

Comment: the `hidden_field_id: true` doesn't do anything. Can you provide us info about the models you're using?

Comment: it used to be container_returns[] but ultimately that is just a param name for the collection so shouldn't matter what it is called. It didn't fix it putting it back as that. Taking out the collection parameter just takes it back to a single commit so nothing there either. The hidden_field_id is there for if I want to edit multiple later. There is only one model and this form should just be sending information to create multiple instances of it.

Comment: So if id add an ID to my object it works the way I would expect. I guess it doesn't like something about the ContainerReturn.new object having nil id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the update, if I add an ID to the initial create it builds the correct array that I was expecting. What I also found was if I send through an index position that also works.

```
<% @container_returns.each_with_index do |container_return, index| %>
  <%= fields_for 'returns[]', container_return, index: index do |cr| %>
  [...]
```

gives me what I was expecting

```
Parameters: {
  "returns"=>{"0"=>{"container_id"=>"400",...},
              "1"=>{"container_id"=>"401",...},
              etc.
             },
  "commit"=>"lots of returns"
}
```